# RxAndroid Update Field/Textview when String Value Changes

Tags: android, observer-pattern, rx-java, rx-android

I am just getting started with RxJava/RxAndroid and I was wondering if I can use it to solve the following problem. Basically, given a Field, say a textview, and a value, a string, I am looking for a way to automatically update the textview whenever the value of the string changes. I am not sure exactly how I would implement this as an Observable. Let me demonstrate;

```
String str = "Test"; //the string value
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView); //the textview

Observable o = //looking for this part. Want to observe the String str

o.subscribe(new Observer<String>() { //subscribe here looking for string changes

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                System.out.println("Completed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String s) {
                textView.setText(s); //update the textview here
            }

        });

//here is where the string changes, it could be hardcoded, user input, or   
//anything else really, I just want the textview to be updated automatically 
//without another setText

str = "Different String";
```

Is what I am looking for possible with RxAndroid/RxJava?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish that would be to use any kind of of `Subject`, maybe either a `BehaviorSubject` or a `PublishSubject`. A `Subject` is both a `Subscriber` (so you can put values into it with `onNext`) and an `Observable` (so you can subscribe to it). Look here for an explanation of the differences: http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html

So, instead of

```
String str = "Test";
```

you would have

```
BehaviorSubject<String> stringSubject = BehaviorSubject.<String>create("Test");
```

You can then directly subscribe to `stringObservable`.

And instead of assigning a new value to your variable like this:

```
str = "Hello World!";
```

you would do

```
stringSubject.onNext("Hello World!");
```

Oh, and never leave `onError` empty - doing so will quietly swallow any exceptions that may have occured earlier, and you will sit and wonder why nothing is happening. At least write `e.printStacktrace()`.

Comment: Works well. Question though, for something as simple as changing a view, this seems like it would be a little much. Is there any reason this would be better than just a setText?

Comment: Yes, if that is the only thing you want to do then RxJava is certainly not worth the effort. But - in my opinion - it already makes things somewhat more readable when you use it for, say, a single asynchronous network request; and it really shines if you want to combine or chain multiple `Observable`s, filter the results, etc. But for your example, yes, too much effort for no real gain.